# Debug JS in chrome

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

Earlier, when the variable in the Java script was not defined, and you tried to use it, the chrome console showed that the variable was not defined. This has disappeared from the new versions. Firefox correctly displays errors. Is it possible to activate the output of an error about undefined variables?

Answer (score 0):

It didn't disappear, see for yourself: hit `F12`, and type `a.undefined()`. You'll get a `ReferenceError: a is not defined`.